# Lazyload Angular Module from URL with singleton services

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular7, systemjs

How to lazyload angular modules and have exposed services as singletons?

- App lazyLoads ModA & ModB
- ModAComponent puts some data into ModAService
- ModB gets data from ModAService

But:

- I dont know any of the Modules Names
- I dont have any of the Modules at compilling time (they are external modules)
- Modules are uploaded to a folder by anyone
- I have to lazyLoad Modules from a URL and consume it

Based on https://itnext.io/how-to-build-a-plugin-extensible-application-architecture-in-angular5-736890278f3f

**Load UMD Modules with SystemJS:**

```js
declare const SystemJS: any;

constructor(private compiler: Compiler,
            private injector: Injector,
) {}

/**
 * Get all file names (Modules) in system path (Backend)
 */
... for each Module found

SystemJS.import('/src/ModA.umd.js' & '/src/ModB.umd.js').then((moduleToCompile) => {

    return this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(moduleToCompile['ModuleA' & 'ModuleB']);

}).then((modFac: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {

    modFac.create(this.injector);

});
```

**Load Module component into ViewChild (Same as Section 1):**

```js
this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync<any>(modFac.moduleType)
.then((factory) => {

    // Get needed component
    const myFactory = factory.componentFactories.filter((component) => {
          return component.componentType.name === 'MyComponent';
    })[0];

    this.MyViewChild.createComponent(actionsFactory);
});
```

After that ModAComponent puts some data into ModAService

**But ModB don't see any data from ModAService**

```
mod-loader.service.ts:16 Loading Module ModLazyAModule
18:58:36.065 app.component.ts:40 Waiting before importing LazyModuleB
18:58:36.068 core.js:16829 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
18:58:36.146 mod-lazy-a.service.ts:11 ModLazyA Service constructor
18:58:36.147 mod-lazy-a.module.ts:13 ModLazyA Module constructor
18:58:36.147 mod-lazy-a.module.ts:15 Pushing data from ModLazyA Module constructor
18:58:36.147 mod-lazy-a.module.ts:17 data ["some Data from ModLazyA Module constructor"]
18:58:36.148 mod-lazy-a.component.ts:16 ModLazyA Component constructor
18:58:36.150 mod-lazy-a.component.ts:20 Pushing data from ModLazyA Component ngOnInit
18:58:36.150 mod-lazy-a.component.ts:22 data (2) ["some Data from ModLazyA Module constructor", "some Data from ModLazyA Component ngOnInit"]
18:58:37.640 mod-loader.service.ts:16 Loading Module ModLazyBModule
18:58:37.664 mod-lazy-a.service.ts:11 ModLazyA Service constructor
18:58:37.665 mod-lazy-b.module.ts:15 ModLazyB Module constructor
18:58:37.665 mod-lazy-b.module.ts:17 Getting data from ModLazyB Module constructor
18:58:37.665 mod-lazy-b.module.ts:18 data []
18:58:37.666 mod-lazy-b.component.ts:16 ModLazyB Component constructor
18:58:37.667 mod-lazy-b.component.ts:20 Getting data from ModLazyB Component constructor
18:58:37.667 mod-lazy-b.component.ts:21 data []
```

**REPO: https://github.com/infnada/angularLazyTest**

---

- Is there any way to load Modules with exposed services using SystemJS as singleton services?
- Is there any way to load Modules from URL(like external) using SystemJsNgModuleLoader?
- Any alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: Please focus on the **minimal** part of a [mcve] (although you have made a very thorough question, which is very rare on this website, so bravo !)

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/lmeijdam/angular-umd-dynamic-example